# How TeamCity computes changes

Tags: git, teamcity

How does Teamcity compute changes? I have build configuration for automatic pullrequest build from Github and after pullrequest TeamCity computes 1000+ changes.

[image]

VCS config:

**Default branch:**
`refs/heads/master`

**Branch specification:**
`+:refs/pull/*/head`

I need to compute only changes contains in current pull request.

Answer (score 3):

It computes against the last `Default Branch` **execution**.

That means you have to execute `Default Branch` even if you are not interested in its result to create a "baseline".

It not only considers changes from the repository but also from changes in build configuration.